# Gcloud Test Case Failing While Building Using Gradle in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

We were using Jenkins, Gradle and GCloud. Test cases were failing only when we run in Jenkins but locally all the test cases were passing. Getting following exception while running test case. We could see test cases that are dealing with Datastore operations are failing.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Commit().
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:672)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:623)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:595)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are the tests running against the datastore emulator or against a live project?  What version of each of the tools are you using?

Comment: @JimMorrison
Are the tests running against the datastore emulator or against a live project?
Datastore Emulator
What version of each of the tools are you using?
appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3, com.google.appengine - 1.9.69 and Jenkins - 1.631

Comment: After updating to the latest version ( 1.9.73 ) of appengine dependency resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After updating to the latest version ( 1.9.73 ) of appengine dependency resolved the issue. Thanks!